# Deriving Feynman Rules (with the presence of a gluon field strength tensor)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, interactions

If I have a Lagrangian of the form:

$$ \mathcal{L} = k \bar{\psi} \varepsilon^{\mu \nu} \lambda^a \phi G^a_{\mu \nu} + h.c. $$

[where $\phi, \psi$ are fermions, $\lambda^a$ are Gellmann matrices, $\varepsilon^{\mu \nu} $ is some antisymmetric tensor and $G^a_{\mu \nu}$ is the gluon field stength tensor.]

And I want to have the Feynman rule for the vertex and it's conjugate I would usually compute the following:

$$ \frac{\delta S}{\delta \psi \delta \phi \delta A_\mu^a} $$
[where $A_\mu$ is a gluon field].

Following that prescription, I have 
$$ S = k \int d^4 x   \bar{\psi} \varepsilon^{\mu \nu} \lambda^a \phi G^a_{\mu \nu}  $$
ignoring color for a moment,
$$ \implies  \frac{\delta S}{\delta \psi \delta \phi } = 2k \int d^4 x \gamma^0 \varepsilon^{\mu \nu} \left( \partial_\mu A_\nu + i g_s A_\mu A_\nu \right)  $$

using the convention that $G_{\mu \nu} =  \partial_\mu A_\nu -  \partial_\nu A_\mu + i g_s \left[ A_\mu, A_\nu \right] $

Taking the Fourier transform to do the last variation I get a leftover $A_\mu$ in the expression though, don't I?

Something seems off here.

With a nicer field strength tensor, like $F^{\mu \nu}$ I get a nice expression at the end only in terms of the momentum of the photon field...here I have a leftover term involving an $A_\mu$.

The initial variation shouldn't be with respect to the field strength tensor, should it?

I'm messing up something trivial, could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a vertex with one gluon, and also a vertex with two gluons.